# How to Create a Bitmap Programmatically?

Tags: winapi, image, bmp

I'd like to create programmatically a random X height and Y width bitmap file.

The content, for me, is irrelevant. It could be all white, empty. What is important is the dimension.

How to do it using Windows API?

Comment: I'd like to do it with Windows API... Then it really doesn't matter. VB6, C++, you choose

Answer (score 2):

You wish to create a Bitmap File using the windows API? There is no specific helper for this. a BMP file however is very simple:

- Write out a `BITMAPFILEHEADER` struct.
- Write out a `BITMAPINFO` struct.
- Write out an array of bytes, enough to hold the format and dimensions described in the `BITMAPINFO` struct.

The MSDN has an [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402(VS.85).aspx) with sample code demonstrating how.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have Microsoft .NET 2.0 Framework installed. (1.1 is also usable).

Using Notepad, create test.cs file with this code:

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 3)
                new System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Convert.ToInt32(args[0]), System.Convert.ToInt32(args[1]))
                    .Save(args[2] + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            else
                System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: test.exe 100 200 filename");
        }
    }
}
```

Then create test.cmd file with this code:

```
@echo off
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /t:exe test.cs
```

Execute test.cmd

Execute text.exe

Answer (score 0):

In .Net you can just new up a Bitmap object:

```
Image myImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
```

Comment: .NET isn't a choice, I'd like to do it using only the Windows API

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on making an image with windows API,you should use Gdi32.dll
In C# just call

Import dll file into your assembly, so you can use external methods in

```
DllImport["Gdi32.dll"]
```

```
HBITMAP CreateCompatibleBitmap(
  HDC hdc, 
  int nWidth, 
  int nHeight
);
```

Then call Bitmap class from this Bitmap like

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap( nameOfBitmap );
bmp.Save("C:\NewImage.jpg");
```

There is an example in msdn page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908165.aspx)

Comment: How would that solve his problem? He can't save a BMP file that way.

Comment: Creating bitmap is important in this question not saving !

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ includes commands to load/save BMP images in C++. This sample code shows how to load and save images: [Converting a BMP Image to a PNG Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533837%28VS.85%29.aspx). The Bitmap class also has a [ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536313%28VS.85%29.aspx) that takes a width, a height and a pixel format to create empty images.